# Best way for comparing string arrays (Custom command line commands)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, compare

In my application I am making a custom command line. I am looking for the best way to check user entered commands and argument agains the arguments I have defined. Take the following example command (which works if user enter it right and in order)

```
do>Drawer /X:Time /Y:Current /N:Window NAme /D:Description
```

Now I want to have a method to does the checking for me:

```
private string CheckDrawerArgs(string[] args)
{
    var mustExist = new string[4]{"X:", "Y:", "N:", "D:"};

    if(args.Length != mustExist.Length)
    {
        return "Arguments are not completly defined. use 'Drawer /?' for help.";
    }

    var argsAreRight = false;

    var flat = from s1 in args
               from s2 in mustExist
               where s1.StartsWith(s2) 

        //how to check if all elements provided 
        // in args does look 
        // like (Starts with) elements in mustExist

        ;
    if(argsAreRight == false)
    {
        return "Bad arguments";
    }

    //Proceed with rest...
}
```

So what I am looking for, is to check if required arguments which are provided by user, are in the `args` also they are not duplicated while the order of them would not effect the checking...

Looking forward for tips!

Comment: Why are you parsing the command line arguments yourself instead of using one of the many existing libraries that do so?

Comment: Hmmm I dont know any yet but anyway it is good to know how to do it...learning something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to Henk's answer following is tested and working

```
 var allpresent = args.Length == mustExist.Length && args.All(c =>
                                                     mustExist.Any(e =>
                                                     c.ToString().StartsWith(e)));
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend writing it in a more reusable way. The fact that all parameters must be given should not be hard-coded into the logic of the parameter parser. You should just check for that in the end, right before you "proceed with rest".

What I generally do in such cases is the following:

First of all, for each one of the possible arguments I have some variables which contain reasonable defaults (so that the argument can be omitted) a trivial example of which would be `bool argument_x_given = false;`

So, I loop over the given arguments, and inside the loop I check the current argument against each and every one of the possible arguments, to find which one it is. If not found, we have an error. If a matching argument is found, then I parse the rest of the argument (the stuff after the ':') and I set the variables which are associated with the argument. While doing this, I check to make sure that the argument is not a duplicate. In the trivial example here, that would be `if( argument_x_given ) { --error-- } else { argument_x_given = true; ... }`.

Finally, once the loop is done, I make sure that all the required arguments were given.

So, what I am trying to say is that you will not gain anything by comparing the string arrays, because you are going to have to make sense out of each and every one of your arguments anyway, and also comparing the string arrays is like trying to take advantage of a situation which is very specific to the problem at hand and not reusable at all.

Answer (score 1):

None of the examples provided account for the forward slash characters that each command line argument starts with. You might need to change your mustExist to include the forward slashes:

```
var mustExist = new string[4]{"/X:", "/Y:", "/N:", "/R:"};
```

The other option is to strip them off of the args before the comparison.